# Workaround: <Select>ing the first <option> never fires an onchange event

Tags: javascript, events, onchange

I have a select-option block on a webpage, and I want it to fire for ANY of the options that get selected in it. However, the first option never fires onselect: Not even if a later option was selected previously.

For example, if my code reads:

```
Settings:
Sensitivity: <select id="sensitivity" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) ajaxUpdateConfig();">
  <option value="25">25%</option>
  <option value="50">50%</option>
  <option value="100" selected>100</option>
</select>
```

...then selecting the first option, 25%, never fires the onchange() event.

Similarly, if the first option is the default value, and the user changes away from it and then wants to return back to it, that doesn't fire the onchange event, either.

Note: I'm aware that the standard answer to the "First selection doesn't generate onchange events" problem is to make a dummy (disabled) first option. But that doesn't fit the design of this page: The menu represents shows the current status while offering the options that the user could change the settings to. Having a dummy entry is bad interface design, for this page.

Comment: SLaks has the answer, but I'm pretty sure you want to use `onchange` not `onselect`.

Comment: Right you are. That's what I get from quoting the code while I'm in the midst of trying other different options than onchange. It should indeed be onchange - edited to correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.selectedIndex` is `0` for the first option.
`0` is falsy, so your `if` never fires.

Get rid of the `if` entirely; there's no reason for it.